# Run a command with wildcards in each subdirectory

Tags: files, find, recursive

I use this command to make a montage of all the images in a directory:

```
gmic *jpg -gimp_montage 4,\""V(H(0,1),H(2,V(3,4)))"\",1,1.0,0,5,0,0,0,255,0,0,0,0 -o -0000."$(date)".jpg
```

I want to run this command in a directory and its subdirectories recursively. So in each directory I would create a montage of the images in that directory.

I tried:

```
find -exec gmic *jpg -gimp_montage 4,\""V(H(0,1),H(2,V(3,4)))"\",1,1.0,0,5,0,0,0,255,0,0,0,0 -o -0000."$(date)".jpg
```

but it gave me the error

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

I also tried

```
find -exec gmic -gimp_montage 4,\""V(H(0,1),H(2,V(3,4)))"\",1,1.0,0,5,0,0,0,255,0,0,0,0 -o -0000."$(date)".jpg {} \;
```

which gave me the following error:

```
[gmic]-0./ Start G'MIC interpreter.
[gmic]-0./ Output image [] as file '-0000.Fri Mar 13 04:33:44 EDT 2015.jpg', with quality 100%.
[gmic]-0./ *** Error *** Command '-output': File '-0000.Fri Mar 13 04:33:44 EDT 2015.jpg', instance list (0,(nil)) is empty.
[gmic] *** Error in ./ *** Command '-output': File '-0000.Fri Mar 13 04:33:44 EDT 2015.jpg', instance list (0,(nil)) is empty.
```

Comment: As you seem to have problems with your quoting, you should just make a script that takes a single parameter that calls `gimp` with the right parameters. Make sure you put the `$1` in the script between double quotes (`"$1"`)

Comment: @Anthon I don't understand your directions. I should make a bash script, like [this](http://i.imgur.com/Se3kn4o.png)? And then run the script with the find -exec command?

Comment: @user8547 No, IMO you approach this the wrong way. You should make a script that takes one parameter (a directory) and does the right thing (e.g. cd into the directory and call the gimp command while expanding files using '*jpg', (alternative: use full path to JPEG: `"$1"/*jpg`))). Then use `find`, to only generate a list of directory names and call the script with those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so you want to run a command in each directory in a directory tree — the current directory, its subdirectories, their subdirectories, etc. The first thing to do is enumerate the directories in question. With the `find` command, tell it to list only directories:

```
find . -type d
```

The command you want to run in each directory is

```
gmic ./*jpg -gimp_montage 4,\""V(H(0,1),H(2,V(3,4)))"\",1,1.0,0,5,0,0,0,255,0,0,0,0 -o -0000."$(date)".jpg
```

This is a shell command, containing a wildcard expansion and a command substitution. You need to run a shell to execute it. Since this shell will be told what to do by `find`, it isn't going to be the shell that you're running `find` in: you need to tell `find` to run a shell. Pass the directory where you want to act as an argument to the shell.

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '…' {} \;
```

Before you can call `gmic`, you need to do a couple of things in that script: change to the directory in question, and check that it contains `.jpg` files.

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
  cd "$0" || exit
  set -- *.jpg
  if [ -e "$1" ]; then
    gmic "$@" -gimp_montage 4,\""V(H(0,1),H(2,V(3,4)))"\",1,1.0,0,5,0,0,0,255,0,0,0,0 -o -0000."$(date)".jpg
  fi
' {} \;
```

Alternatively, you could tell `find` to list `.jpg` files. However that makes it difficult to execute the command only one per directory.

If your shell is bash, as opposed to plain `sh`, you can use its `**` wildcard to recurse into directories. This is easier than using `find`. In bash ≤4.2, beware that `**` traverses symbolic link to directories as well. You can simplify the file existence test a little as well.

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for dir in ./**/*/; do
  files=("$dir/"*.jpg)
  if [[ ${#files[@]} -ne 0 ]]; then
    gmic "${files[@]}" -gimp_montage 4,\""V(H(0,1),H(2,V(3,4)))"\",1,1.0,0,5,0,0,0,255,0,0,0,0 -o "$dir/-0000.$(date)".jpg
  fi
done
```

In zsh, you can use a [history modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) in a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to enumerate directories containing `.jpg` files, then filter the resulting array to keep a single copy of each directory.

```
dirs=(./**/*.jpg(:h))
for dir in ${(u)dirs}; do
  gmic $dir/*.jpg -gimp_montage 4,\""V(H(0,1),H(2,V(3,4)))"\",1,1.0,0,5,0,0,0,255,0,0,0,0 -o "$dir/-0000.$(date).jpg"
done
```

(Aside: `-0000.Sat Mar 14 15:51:28 CET 2015.jpg` is a really weird name for a file. Files whose name begins with `-` tend to cause problems because they look like options for commands. Dates are more convenient to manipulate in a format where sorting lexicographically is identical to sorting chronologically, such as `20150314-145128`.)

Comment: Tx that worked! I used the first solution. It gave me an error message on first run: `find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter` I deleted the hyphen in front of `-d` and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

As with the rest of the comments, I am not sure what you would need for something to allow you to run any command more than either -exec, or piping bits into a while or for loop.  The exec option will allow you to use "{}" in place of whatever it found (full path, not relative).  Here is a quick example of both the -exec option and the for loop.

```
$ tree
.
|-- a
|   |-- a
|   |   `-- a
|   `-- b
`-- b
    |-- a
    `-- b

7 directories, 0 files
$ find . -type d -exec touch {}/foo \
$ tree
.
|-- a
|   |-- a
|   |   |-- a
|   |   |   `-- foo
|   |   `-- foo
|   |-- b
|   |   `-- foo
|   `-- foo
|-- b
|   |-- a
|   |   `-- foo
|   |-- b
|   |   `-- foo
|   `-- foo
`-- foo

7 directories, 8 files
$ for i in $(find . -type f); do mv $i $i.moved; done
$ tree
.
|-- a
|   |-- a
|   |   |-- a
|   |   |   `-- foo.moved
|   |   `-- foo.moved
|   |-- b
|   |   `-- foo.moved
|   `-- foo.moved
|-- b
|   |-- a
|   |   `-- foo.moved
|   |-- b
|   |   `-- foo.moved
|   `-- foo.moved
`-- foo.moved

7 directories, 8 files
```